# How can I use Protobuf in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, protocol-buffers, nativescript-plugin, protobuf.js

I would like to use protobuf in a NativeScript app, however I'm struggling to figure out how, as it seems like NativeScript [doesn't support binary](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/570) over the wire.

I know NativeScript apps can use protobuf, because I'm pretty sure the [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) does.  How is this plugin able to use protobuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/570) to support binary data in Http requests.

The workaround is to use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/) plugin which does support uploading binary data to remote server.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-background-http
```

Comment: Thx. From what I can tell this requires reading a file from a path.  You suggesting writing PB to a file on device?

Comment: Yes, that should help. Simply point the file name to upload then.

Comment: Thanks.  That will prob work but seems error prone and messy. nativescript-plugin-firebase does not use this method, how is this plugin using protobuf? Is protobuf being used inside native code, invoked via the JS bridge from the plugin?

Comment: The plugin has it's own native SDK does the job. You are free to use the native apis and send the binary data directly if you want to.

Comment: When you say "native apis" you mean the native HTTP libs (ex: OkHttp). Don't happen to have an example of this by chance do you?

Comment: Yes, I could be OkHttp (Android) or the equivalent on iOS. NativeScript too uses OkHttp internally, you can check their source code. Refer [Java to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) guide to understand about accessing Java apis in JS / TS.